# URL form retrieval and submission via flash?

Tags: html, actionscript-3

Totally new to flash and actionscript. What I want to do is retrieve a URL into a page (probably in a hidden frame or something), populate the form it contains with the correct fields (via my script), including possible data to upload, then submit it back. I guess an analogy use-case would be if I had a user choose a picture and then which site to upload it to (tinypic, flickr, etc), the script would download the main page, fill in the form data, attach the pic, and submit it. I saw a similar example in php somewhere, but I need to do it in flash.
I can probably get it eventually by myself, but if someone could point me in the right direction (keywords, functions to use/avoid, etc) I'd really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than retrieving the form and trying to fill it out just use actionscript to directly post to the server side script.